How to move a process with user-interaction to background and back?
I have a Debian 12 with Bash as console.
How can I have a process with user-interaction (e.g. top, nano, ...) that I can keep running but send it into background and get it back from there?
It should keep running when in background!

I read about fg and bg but I am not sure about process vs job.
I also tried Ctrl+Z but that does not keep it running.


Looks a tmux/screen task

Please [edit] your question and add more details about your use case. Why can't you use separate terminal windows, separate virtual consoles or separate SSH connections for switching between different processes?

For top or nano, why do you need to keep it running? Either program will do just fine being suspended while in the background

Ctrl+Z stops a process, which gives you your prompt back. bg starts it in the background. This works with top, until top requires user input. A background process cannot get input from the user, so it stops again.

Following up on what @PeterBill pointed out, a process like vim or nano that relies on user input has no real business running in the background because all it'll do is wait for user input that won't happen until it gets foregrounded again. Your question makes exceedingly little sense as is and I think you should stop using "for example" and tell us the actual use case you're looking for.
